# ID3 training and testing

Tags: java, id3

I know this is not a code problem but I need to code it and I can't understand the concept. I have implemented an ID3 and the output is the tree printed in the form of rules (works fine). Now I wish to train and test this ID3,however, I have analysed that if you removed half of the data set and built the tree a different tree will be generated, so how can you test it exactly?